# How to write LegacySQL in Excel ODBC connection to BigQuery?

Tags: sql, excel, google-bigquery, odbc

I am trying to get data from a LegancySQL View in BigQuery using the Excel ODBC Simba Connection, but it is saying "Cannot reference a legacy SQL view in a standard SQL Query". However, I can't seem to be able to write it as LegacySQL. Adding in #legacySQL at the start of the query gives another error saying that legacySQL is not allowed, however, in their documentation it says it is used by default..?

What can I do?

Thanks,

Benji

Comment: Can you define a separate view using standard SQL instead?

Comment: I have just found this out, I thought you could only save a view using LegacySQL. However, question still stands of if you can write LegacySQL for this connector, and how if so?

Comment: I'm not sure in particular how you can set the dialect as part of the ODBC connector through Excel. The BigQuery team strongly recommends using standard SQL queries and views if possible, though, since that's where all of our development is focused.